# using sed with echo and reading from a file

Tags: unix, sed

I want to delete directory path except the file name using sed from an html file. The path looks like:

```
<a href="/dir1/dir2/file.mp3" other_tags_here </a>
```

with spaces (%) and other characters in the directory and file names. eg.

```
<a href="/1-%one%2026/two%20_three%four/1-%eight.mp3"
```

I just need to keep `<a href="1-%eight.mp3" other_tags_here <a/>`. When I try

```
echo '<a href=/1-%one%2026/two%20_three%four/1-%eight.mp3' | sed 's|href="/.*/.*/|href="|g'
```

it works fine. However when I read from the html file

```
sed 's|href="/.*/.*/|href="|g' file.html
```

it deletes every thing after `href=` and returns only `href=`. How do I correct this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sed, regexes match the leftmost longest match.  That means that the final `.*/` in your regex will match to the final `/` on the line.  To prevent that:

```
sed 's|href="/[^/]*/[^/]*/|href="|g' file.html
```

The regex `[^/]*/` will match to the next `/` only.

In languages like python or perl we can address this issue by using non-greedy regexes.  Because sed does not support non-greedy regexes, we must try to achieve a similar effect using tricks like `[^/]*/`.

**Standard Warning:**  In general, html format can be very complex with lots of special cases that regexes are ill-suited to handle. 
 When working with html, it is generally best to use html-specific tools (like python's beautifulsoup).